# facebook can't resolve URL

Tags: javascript, facebook

Am trying to build a facebook share button, but I keep getting an error message inside the share popup screen when I click the button

```
Could not resolve object at URL http://localhost:8080/App/templates/property-template.xhtml?propertyId=1#
```

I tried to use `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` but got same result.

am using jsf with javascript to accomplish this.

**JSF**

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-o btn-facebook"
 onclick="share(window.location.href);"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook</a>
```

**javascript**

```
function share(url) {

    console.log(url);
    FB.ui({
        method : 'share',
        href : url,
    }, function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
            alert('Posting completed.');
        } else {
            alert('Error while posting.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook SDK share method instructs the Facebook crawler to fetch open graph tags from your page to be shared. And since it's running on a local host, it cannot be accessed by Facebook.
More info can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web)

Comment: but If i set the url to  something else... like www.google.com, it works fine

Comment: Exactly. www.google.com is accessible by Facebot, your localhost is not. Try exposing your local development environment with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) for example, and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you @Attila, it works fine, unfortunately i spend a few hours to sole that problem before saw your answer